# Cannot invoke 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock'

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift

I've checked the syntax a gazillion times here, on GitHub, parse.com & elsewhere, without any luck. The problem is when I'm calling saveInBackgroundWithBlock for PFObject I get the the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool, NSError) -> Void)'

I'm on Xcode 6.3 beta 2. All frameworks are loaded to the project (including Bolts & Parse, but not provided by parse.com ParseCrashReporting & ParseUI), `<Parse/Parse.h>` & even `<Bolts/Bolts.h>` are brought through the Bridge Header.

```
var score = PFObject(className: "score")
    score.setObject("Rob", forKey: "name")
    score.setObject(95, forKey: "scoreNumber")
    score.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError) -> Void in
        if success == true {
            println("Score created with ID: \(score.objectId)")
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 1.2 the declaration of .saveInBackgroundWithBlock should look like this:

```
Void saveInBackgroundWithBlock(block: PFBooleanResultBlock?(Bool, NSError?) -> Void)
```

So it should have been as follows:

```
score.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Comment: Xcode 7 beta 5 shows error: 
`Cannot invoke 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool, NSError?) -> Void)'`

Answer (score 9):

The `error` parameter is supposed to be an implicitly unwrapped optional, but not the `success` one:

```
(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
              ^               ^
```

However unless you need to specify the type for whatever reason, I suggest you to use the closure simply as:

```
(success, error) in
```

less prone to type declaration errors.

Comment: Thank you, dear sir, you pointed me in the right direction! Your advice, however, was not exactly correct, please see my answer below.

Comment: The only difference is the implicitly unwrapped optional, which you can always declare as normal optional. Did you get an error because of that?

Comment: Yes, I get an error whenever I change any of this.
Yet, '(success, error) in' seems to be working, but that's not what I wanted there.

Answer (score 1):

The method wants the `success` and `error` variables set like this with the `!` on the `error`:

```
(success: Bool, error: NSError!)
              ^               ^
```

But you've set the `!` to the wrong variable:

```
(success: Bool!, error: NSError)
```

As you see here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28898010/4327488